# Safari Extension : How to add menu and sub menu on bars?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

Here I am working with safari extension development. I have successfully get developer certificate on safari browser.

Here I am able to create menu and sub menu on toolbar item but as per my project requirement I have to include menu and menu items in bar.

Please suggest me way to done this thing.

Advance thanks...

Comment: You can't use SafariExtensionMenu objects in extension bars. You'll have to duplicate the functionality of your menu using a standard HTML <select> element in the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Googling exercise provided me with following two descriptive articles.

1. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingContextualMenuItems/AddingContextualMenuItems.html
2. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-safari-extension-from-scratch--net-15050